# Excel Columns to Spacy Docu (Tokens, Lemmas)

Tags: python-3.x, spacy

I have been trying to figure this out for days now.  But - I am trying to upload data from an excel file.  I then remove missing values and combined two text columns into one.  At that point, I have a dataframe that shows about 3,000 rows of different customer comments.  Next I want to run Spacy so I can do some dependency parsing.  The problem is that I keep running into a situation where it doesn't parse the individual words.

I've tried using an apply approach.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import spacy
from spacy import displacy
nlp=spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')

df = pd.read_excel (r"C:\Users\GBarnett\Downloads\NPS Survey2019.xlsx")
df.dropna(axis=0, subset=['Neg','Pos'], thresh=1)
df["Combined"]=df["Pos"].map(str) + df["Neg"].map(str)
df['Combined']=df['Combined'].str.replace('nan','')
df['Combined']=df['Combined'].astype(str)
doc = df['Combined'].apply(lambda x: nlp(x))
for token in doc:
    print(token.text, token.lemma_)
```

There are no errors until the lemma_

AttributeError: 'spacy.tokens.doc.Doc' object has no attribute 'lemma_'

And if I run:

```
for token in doc:
print(token.text)
```

Then the outcome does not look like tokens.  Basically it is just line after line like this:

we have an access problem for last 6 months. Although we contacted with your techincal services they counld not fixed it
Because you prevent users doing training with whichever training provider in whatever part of the country they want to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are trying to get Spacy to parse through some texts and get the lemma form of each token. I am going to only post the relevant part of the code which you think you must tweak and not other steps like cleaning stopwords, punctuations, etc.

You can do this by:

```
from __future__ import print_function, unicode_literals
import pandas as pd
import spacy

df = pd.read_excel('dataset.xlsx')

nlp = spacy.load('en')
tokens = []
lemma = []
for doc in nlp.pipe(df['Combined'].astype('unicode').values, batch_size = 50, n_threads = 3):
    if doc.is_parsed:
        tokens.append([n.text for n in doc])
        lemma.append([n.lemma_ for n in doc])
    else:
        tokens.append(None)
        lemma.append(None)

df_new = pd.DataFrame()
df_new['Lemma'] = lemma
df_new['Tokens'] = tokens
```

You should now see your tokens and corresponding lemma.

Comment: Thank you this worked great!  I guess maybe I don't understand certain things well enough yet.  Right now if I do something like:
`displacy.render(doc, style='dep')`

I get: UserWarning: [W005] Doc object not parsed. This means displaCy won't be able to generate a dependency visualization for it.  Is there a way to use "doc" still... For example, if there is a sentence that I would like to build a dependency tree for, how do I get it to look in the right place?  Is there a way to assign various rows to doc where it recognizes the tokens, lemma, ents, pos, etc?